# Probability Simple Question (Airports)

Tags: probability

I have a probability question I can't understand.

> In a fly from Berlin to Porto, it was verified that there was a baggage of a client missing. The baggage's were transferred 3 times by air companies and the probability where the transference wouldn't make it in time is 4/10, 2/10 and 1/10 respectively. What's the probability of a failure from the first air company?

I want to find out what's your induction thought over this question.

The correct answer is: 400/568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just trace through all the possible outcomes that could happen.  In a probability tree.

The first split in the tree is 40% lost[end]/60% made it through.  Then split the 60% branch with 20% lost[end]/80% made it through.  And then split that 80% branch into 10%lost[end]/90% arrived[end].

$$\begin{align}P(\text{Lost at 1})&=40\%\\P(\text{Lost at 2})&=60\%*20\%\\P(\text{Lost at 3})&=60\%*80\%*10\%\end{align}$$

So the probability it was lost at the first stop (given it was lost) would be $$\frac{.4}{.4+.12+.048}$$
or
$$\frac{\frac{4}{10}}{\frac{4}{10}+\frac{3}{25}+\frac{6}{125}}=\frac{400}{568}$$

Comment: Perfect thought, clear and concise. Thank you